# SQL select where conditions 2 if condition 1 doesn't match

Tags: php, sql, subquery, union, where-clause

I am a little embarassed and feels ashamed as it sounds really simple. But I'm brain freezed on this one

I want to get result of a condition if a first condition didn't match anything. Of course I could use a simple `if(!$request)` within my php, but I wanted to know if it was not just possible directly trhough my sql request.

I have done a simple OR but of course this will just return both results to each conditions.

```
SELECT * FROM `menu` WHERE (`id_shop` = $current_shop OR `id_shop` = 0) AND `id_lang` = 1
```

If there is no entries coresponding to the `$current_shop` id, I want to get those where `id_shop` is equal to 0 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If there is no entries coresponding to the $current_shop id, I want to get those where id_shop is equal to 0 instead.

You can do this with `UNION ALL` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `menu` 
WHERE `id_shop` = ? AND `id_lang` = 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM `menu` 
WHERE `id_lang` = 1
  AND `id_shop` = 0 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `menu` WHERE `id_shop` = ? AND `id_lang` = 1)
```

The first member of the query searches for a match with the given parameters. The second parameter falls back on `id_shop` `0` if and only if the first member did not return any row.

Comment: It works, and it looks elegant. I like it. And I didn't knew about UNION ALL that way :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 'menu' WHERE ('id_shop' = $current_shop OR ('id_shop' = 0 AND 'id_shop' 
!= $current_shop)) AND 'id_lang' = 1
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't saw your answer. This is wrong. You will have exactly the same result. `!=` operator doesn't mean "if not", it means "not" or "not equal to". So basicaly it is read like so by the machine `line1: is the id = to $current_shop? yes. Line2 : is the id = to $current_shop? no, the is it equal to 0 but not equal to  $current_shop? Yes, As I just see it was not equal to $current_shop during the previous test`